# Send information from elementor form to another page with the modified data

Tags: wordpress, forms, elementor

I'm building a wordpress site with elementor pro.

I want to make a form (in which you enter some numerical data as metric cubes and other numbers) that redirects you to another page where that data is transformed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use a template with html javascript linked by an external link button

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When redirecting to the other page (eg: `site.com/other-page`) you could include the "numerical data" as a [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) directly in the redirected URL (eg: `site.com/other-page?data=1234`). Then, upon initial loading of the other page, the data can be [retrieved from the URL](https://elementor.com/help/dynamic-request-parameter-pro/)